# Are the Gluon Mobile sample apps available to run online?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I see the sample apps listed here:

http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/#mobile

Are they available to run online someplace?  I would like to send a link to some non-developers so they can check out the samples on their phones.

Comment: No, the samples source code is available only to be downloaded, then you need to build the app yourself.

Comment: It would be great if Gluon put hosted versions of those sample apps up.  Lots of people may want to quickly check them out from their phones.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. First Android it could work, not for iOS though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. You can install them on your device or your friend's  and they work just fine.